# What is the significance of Brachistochrone curve in the real world?

Tags: calculus, geometry, curves

I want to know how does the brachistochrone curve is significant in any real world object or effect. Are there any machines or devices which are based upon the principle of shortest time?

Comment: You can see [Tautochrone curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautochrone_curve) and the conncetion to pendulum. To know the "theoretical" solution may help to search for better "practical" solutions.

Comment: @mathbeing Those are catenaries.  They are not brachistochrones.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yep, apologizes for the confusion.

Comment: Does anyone know any application where its used for its property of short time reach ?

Comment: It seems it has some applications in sports engineering. esp. those related to skiing and/or surfing (ref: [Surfing the branchistochrone](https://engineeringsport.co.uk/2010/10/29/surfing-the-brachistochrone/) )